# OpenCV KeyPoints assertion

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2015, orb

I am trying to implement a code in c++ using opencv 2.4.10 that calculates frame's keypoints with ORB. When I run the code in VS community 2015 it gives me the assertion:

> Program: ...l Studio 2015\Projects\lbplibrary-master\x64\Debug\prova1.exe
>   File: c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\xmemory0
>   Line: 106
>
> Expression: "(_Ptr_user & (_BIG_ALLOCATION_ALIGNMENT - 1)) == 0" && 0
>
> For information on how your program can cause an assertion
>   failure, see the Visual C++ documentation on asserts.

This is the code I am compiling. The execution works and it does the job but at the end I get the assertion!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

#include "stdafx.h"


using namespace cv;
using namespace std;
using namespace lbplibrary;

static bool isFileExist(const String& filename)

{
    /// Open the file
    FILE* f = fopen(filename.c_str(), "rb");

    /// in the event of a failure, return false
    if (!f)
        return false;

    fclose(f);

    return true;
}


string intToStr(int i, string path) {

    string bla = "";
    stringstream ss;
    ss << i;
    string ret = "";
    ss >> ret;
    string name = bla.substr(0, bla.size() - ret.size());

    name = path + name + ret;
    return name;
}


int main(int argc, const char **argv)
{


    //keyframe
    string current_window = "Current frame ";
    Mat Current;


    //keypoints
    vector<KeyPoint> kp;
    Ptr<ORB> detector = FeatureDetector::create("ORB");

    fstream outputFile;

    //elaborate keyframes

    for (int i = 0; i< 178; i++)
    {

        //read and show keyframe 

        string Curr_name = intToStr(i, "dataset/backyard-seq/map/frame");
        Current = imread(Curr_name + ".jpg", 1);
        namedWindow(current_window, WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
        imshow(current_window, Current);

        //calculate frame keypoints

        detector->detect(Current, kp);

        //save keypoints of each keyframe in txt

        if (!isFileExist(Curr_name + ".txt"))
        {
            outputFile.open(Curr_name + ".txt", ios::out);
            for (size_t ii = 0; ii < kp.size(); ++ii)
                outputFile << kp[ii].pt.x << " " << kp[ii].pt.y << std::endl;
            outputFile.close();
        }

        //draw and show keypoints

        Mat out;
        drawKeypoints(Current, kp, out, Scalar::all(255));
        imshow("Keypoints", out);


    }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: by "at the end" you mean during cleanup after `main` has exited?

Comment: **Wrong librarires!** Be sure to use OpenCV compiled with vc14 (you need probably to recompile OpenCV yourself)

Comment: @Miki I need to use opencv 2.4.10, cannot use another version. The problem disappears when I comment the keypoints detect line:

Comment: detector->detect(Current, kp);

Comment: @slawekwin yes the main has exited and if I stop the execution while it's still in the for cycle the program return 0 errors

Comment: You can keep 2.10, just recompile it, or use a visual studio version with prebuilt binaries. What's the path of your opencv libs?

Comment: @Miki for example the highgui library's path is C:\opencv\build\include\opencv2\highgui\highgui.hpp

Comment: Libraries, not the headers. Where is opencv_core210.lib?

Comment: @Miki the path is C:\opencv\build\x64\vc12\staticlib\opencv_core2410.lib but there is the same file also in folder vc10 and vc11

Answer (score 1):

You're using Visual Studio 2015, which means `vc14` compiler.

OpenCV 2.4.10 doesn't have prebuilt binaries for that, but only for `vc10` (Visual Studio 2010), `vc11` (Visual Studio 2012) and `vc12` (Visual Studio 2013).

So you have a few options:

1. Use either Visual Studio 2010, 2011, 2012 linking the correct libraries
2. Recompile OpenCV using `vc14` and use them with Visual Studio 2015.
3. If that's an option, you can switch to OpenCV 3.1, which has prebuilt binaries for `vc14` 64bit.

Comment: can you mean download vc14 folder from openCV 3.1 and copy it in my opencv 2.10. then recompile opencv? thank you for your help I appreciate

Comment: No. I mean either recompile 2.4.10 with vc14, or use 3.1 which already has prebuild binaries for vc14. Don't mix them!

Comment: ok I am going to download cmake and recompile, Unfortunately I need that version of opencv!

Comment: Ok, good. Remember to compile for the same architecture you need in your project (x86 vs x64), in both debug and release.

Comment: I just finished compile opencv 2.10 with vc14 but the assertion still remains

Comment: Have you compiled x64? Are you linking to the correct libraries? Can you show the path to the libraries?

Comment: here's the new path: C:\opencv\build\x64\vc14\lib\Debug

Comment: Did you build also INSTALL project?

Comment: yes if it's the one called OpenCV...I also changed the lib links in the project property...

Comment: ok the problem is when I rebuild both in debug and release it fails cause if gives me 24 errors and 376 warnings

Comment: Here's a pretty handy [how-to guide for OpenCV and Visual Studio 2015 compilation process.](http://dogfeatherdesign.com/opencv-3-0-microsoft-visual-studio-2015-cmake-and-c/)

Comment: Hi @zipzit. thanks, but I  know quite well how to build OpenCV... Please use `@stardust` in your comment, so he'll be notified, too.